# Как с помощью SQL-запроса вывести уникальные свойства товаров по ID категории?

Tags: sql

Сейчас решаю последнюю задачу в тестовом задании по SQL и базам данным, где рассказывается о базе данных, которая имеет 4 таблицы:

- таблица категорий товаров category (id, name);
- таблица товаров product (id,category_id,name,price);
- таблица свойств property (id,name);
- таблица значений свойств товаров property_value (product_id,property_id,value);

И задача заключается в самом условии:

> Получить список названий уникальных свойств товара по названию
> категории (свойство должно быть только у 1 товара в категории)

С такой задачей подобного рода я сталкиваюсь впервые( а вы сталкивались с этим?) и хочу разобраться с SQL-запросом, который позволяет получить уникальный список свойств товаров по индетификатору категории. Так как я имеют опыт работы с SQL около года, с более сложными запросами я не игрался.  Есть от вас вариант такого запроса, используя при этом SELECT DISTINCT, чтобы мне его написать в качестве ответа?

Answer (score 1):

`select category.name, property.name from category join product on category.id = product.category_id join property_value on product.id = property_value.product_id join property on property_value.property_id = property.id group by category.id, property_value.property_id having count(product.id) = 1`